# How do I append a string to the end of an array (list) in bash?

Tags: bash

I have been working on a bash script that is supposed to loop through a list of users you are supposed to have and a list of users on the system. I am currently trying to add the names of users, which are stored in variables, to the end of an array (list). Here is what my code is doing:

```
for x in array
do
    for y in otherArray
    do
        if [[ $x == $y ]]
        then
            newArray += $x
        elif [[ $x != $y ]]
        then
            otherNewArray += $x
        fi
    done
done
```

This returns this error:

```
line [Insert line where I use =+ here] [Insert value of x here] command not found
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Your code contains no `=+`.

Comment: You can also check the script using [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/), checks errors and even offers suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know why this is happening?

This is assignment to variable named `echo`:

```
echo=some_value
```

This runs a command named `echo` with two arguments `=` and `some_value`.

```
echo = some_value
```

The same way the following runs a command named `newArray`

```
newArray += $x
```

The following adds a new array element:

```
newArray+=("$x")
```

The following appends the result of `$x` to the first element in the array:

```
newArray+=$x
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I came from JS and didn't quite realize the syntax.